# asp.net mvc 5 api client authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to access kobotoolbox api to get data from an asp.net mvc 5 site.

Here (https://kc.kobotoolbox.org/api/v1/?format=api) you can see the authentication methods supported.

I've tried token authentication but I got stuck with CORS.

Now I've tried to move to Oauth2 authentication.

I've registered my app and got the clientID, the secret, the authorization endpoint url and the token endpoint url.

I have used code from other articles in a controller action. And I've been redirected to kobotoolbox login url

Here is the code:

```
    public ActionResult KoboLogin()
    {

        var client = new HttpClient();
        var data = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

        data.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["KoboToolboxDataClientId"]));
        data.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("response_type", "code"));
        data.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("state", "blue"));
        FormUrlEncodedContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(data);

        string url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["KoboToolboxAuthorizationEndpoint"];

        var result = client.PostAsync(url, content).Result;

        string redirecturl = result.RequestMessage.RequestUri.ToString();

        return Redirect(redirecturl);
    }
```

Now I'm stuck at this point.

I arrive to the kobotoolbox website, enter authentication but it doesn't return to my app.

I've configured the redirect uri to: http://localhost:50461

Thank you!

Cesc

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  What research have you done?  Have you registered an account with that service?  Showing effort will get people to look at your question, and try to help you through the difficult parts.

Comment: Edited with latest progress

Comment: Well it seems I'm doing well. The problem is on the kobotoolbox website. It doesn't redirect correctly. I hope it'll get corrected soon.